# NHibernate: adding calculated field to query results

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I have inherited an ASP.NET website built on NHibernate, with which I have no experience. I need to add a calculated field based on a column in a related table to an existing query. In SQL, this would be done easily enough using a correlated subquery:

```
select
  field1,
  field2,
  (select count(field3) from table2 where table2.table1ID = table1.ID) calc_field
from
  table1
where
  [criteria...]
```

Unfortunately, of course, I can't use SQL for this. So in reality, I have three related questions:

1. What is the best way to trace through the web of interfaces, base classes, etc used by NHibernate in order to pinpoint the object where I need to add the field?
2. Having located that object, what, if anything, has to be done besides adding a public property to the object corresponding to the new field?
3. Are there any NHibernate-specific considerations with regard to referencing a related object in a query?

Here is the existing code that performs the search:

```
public INHibernateQueryable<C> Search(ISearchQuery query, string sortField)
{
    _session = GetSession();
    var c = _session.Linq<C>();
    c.Expand("IP");
    c.Expand("LL");
    c.Expand("LL.Address");
    c.Expand("LL.Address.City");
    c.Expand("LL.Address.City.State");
    c.Expand("LL.Address.City.County");
    c.Expand("CE");
    c.Expand("IC");
    c.Expand("AR");
    c.Expand("ER");
    c.Expand("Status");
    var res = _SearchFilters
        .Where(x => x.ShouldApply(query))
        .Aggregate(c, (candidates, filter) => (INHibernateQueryable<C>) filter.Filter(candidates, query));

    res = SortSearch(res, sortField);

    return res;
}
```

I appreciate any advice from experienced Hibernators.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in returning a query containing a computed value, you can still call a stored procedure in NHibernate and map the results to a POCO in the same way as you map a table for CRUD operations; obviously read-only instead of updatable.

Have a look at the `ISession.CreateSQLQuery` method; I can post an example from one of my projects if you need one.